# Diagnose a faulty Cat6 ethernet cable not getting 1Gbps

Tags: networking, ethernet, cat6, cabling

I suspect I have a faulty [Cat 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable) Ethernet cable in my house, but I'm unsure how to diagnose it further or what repair options I have. I have Cat 6 cabling in my home and noticed that one of the outlets seems to be operating at 100  Mbit/s. All of the in-wall cables connect up to a 1 Gbit/s switch, which is connected to a fiber-based [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider).

Using [Speedtest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedtest.net) from each outlet, I can get 500-900 Mbit/s from all of the outlets, except one, which gets 92-95 Mbit/s. I did some basic elimination tests; I made sure the patch cables weren't the problem, made sure the port on the switch wasn't an issue, etc. They all point to this in-wall cable seemingly being limited to 100 Mbit/s operation.

What are some further diagnostic steps? How can I repair or salvage the situation? Replacing the entire run in-wall isn't really feasible without some notable demolition.

Comment: a fibre cable has 8 strings. If one doesn't work, only 4 of them will be active, dropping the connection to 100mbps. Usually it's the connectors: check both ends for bent or broken pins, or for dirt. Clean them with alcohol or contact spray. If that doesn't help, the contacts inside the connectors might be broken,  a technician/electrician can substitute the connectors quite easily. A cable will really only break if it is physically damaged.

Comment: A close examination of the termination at each end might reveal a problem. All eight wires must have the same order at both ends. See https://www.lanshack.com/cat5e-tutorial.aspx

Comment: I know you said it's not feasible, but is there any chance you could tie a new cable onto the end of the old cable and just pull the old cable all the way through the run, voila replacement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is likely that 1 or more wires is not connected end-to-end. (100 megabit requires 4 wires, gigabit requires 8)

You can purchase inexpensive testers to test thus -eg https://www.amazon.com.au/iMBAPrice-Network-Cable-Tester-Phone/dp/B01M63EMBQ/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?keywords=network+cable+tester&qid=1682278570&sr=8-3 (Ebay and Aliexpress likely have them even cheaper)

You **might** be able to find/fix the problem by opening the network sockets and carefully checking the order of wires punched into the sockets, and also check they are properly punched down.

You didn't mention it, but I have assumed you have tried devices known to work at gigabit speeds on the 100 megabit connection to rule out the device only having a 100 megabit connection?

Comment: I did rule out the device(s) -- they connect above 100 Mbps on the other outlets. Thanks!

Comment: I got a Klein Tools LAN Scout Jr 2 and it reported a failure with 'Open' on pins 4 and 5, which I believe are the blue pair.

Comment: It certainly could be coincidental but blue/blue-white is typically considered to be the first pair and is typically used for phone/adsl/vdsl - so it may not be a badly punched down pair as much as a pair being used for something else.

Comment: As a follow-up. After I opened up both enclosures, I found that on one end, the wires had broken at the point of the punch down. I trimmed the wires back a bit and reconnected it and it worked.